# Volume of a square pyramid with a curved base

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Consider a square pyramid of base length $a$ and height $H$ with vertices at coordinates $\left(\pm \frac{a}2, \pm \frac{a}2\right)$ and $(0,0,H)$. Assume that $f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \langle 0,H\rangle$ is a $C^1$-function. I'm interested in the volume $V$ of the pyramid above the surface $z = f(x,y)$.

The idea is to divide the pyramid into infinitesimal oblique pyramids (or maybe cones?) with base $dS$ and vertex $(0,0,H)$. By Cavalieri's principle, the volume of such a pyramid is given by
$$dV = \frac13h\,dS$$
where $h$ is the height of the pyramid, which is equal to $H-z$ where $z$ is the $z$-coordinate of the base $dS$. It remains to do a surface integral
$$V = \frac13\iint_S (H-z)\,dS(x,y,z).$$
Now, we can parameterize the surface $S$ using the orthographic projection from the vertex $(0,0,H)$ onto the base:
$$\varphi : \left[-\frac{a}2, \frac{a}2\right]^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3, \qquad \varphi(u,v) = \left(u\left(1-\frac{f(u,v)}H\right),v\left(1-\frac{f(u,v)}H\right),f(u,v)\right).$$
[image: parameterization]
Therefore, if my calculations are correct, we get
\begin{align}
V &= \frac13\iint_{\left[-\frac{a}2, \frac{a}2\right]^2} (H-f(u,v))\,\left\|\partial_u\varphi(u,v)\times \partial_v\varphi(u,v)\right\| du\,dv\\
&= \frac{H}3\iint_{\left[-\frac{a}2, \frac{a}2\right]^2} \left(1-\frac{f(u,v)}H\right)^2 \sqrt{\partial f_u(u,v)^2 + \partial f_v(u,v)^2 + \left(1-\frac{f(u,v) -u\,\partial_uf(u,v)-v\,\partial_vf(u,v)}{H}\right)^2} du\,dv.
\end{align}

**My question is:** is this approach (at least conceptually) correct? I'm quite uncertain about the part with the computation of the volume of the oblique pyramid with infinitesimal base $dS$ and then summing such volumes up.

FWIW, I've plugged in the case of the constant function $f(x,y) = C$ and it gives
$$V = \frac13 (H-C)\left(a\left(1-\frac{C}H\right)\right)^2$$
as expected.

Comment: To apply Cavalieri's principle, the height of the oblique pyramids should be measured perpendicular to the base. $H-f(u,v)$ measures the height perpendicular to the square base of the pyramid, but the normal to the surface at the base of the of the oblique pyramid is not necessarily perpendicular to the square base.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks a lot for your comment, I was worried about exactly this sort of thing. So the expression should instead be the length of the orthogonal projection of the vector $(x,y,f(x,y))-(0,0,H)$ onto the normal $n(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, that seems right; dot with the unit normal.